# Copy a button from a browser into an email

Tags: html, email, button, copy

I'd like to make a button in HTML which can be selected and copied into an email, for example:

```
<a href='www.myshop.com/product/add/id/my_id'><input type='button' value='Buy Now'/></a>
```

In a browser, this would look something like this:

[image]

I'd then want the user to be able to select the button by highlighting it like this:

[image]

Copying it to the clipboard, and then pasting it into an email, so that the button is in the email (using a client like Gmail).

Currently, the only way I can do this is by copying pure HTML into an HTML editor, and then copying it from that HTML editor into gmail.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to add an input to an email - most email programs will strip out inputs as they may interfere with their own forms if they are web based

Comment: Not at all, you can use a program like Kompozer (http://kompozer.net/) you can type in the HTML into the source section, and paste the button into an email client. (I've confirmed that this works in Gmail).